# DataTables warning, Requested unknown parameter 'ID' for row 0, column 0

Tags: php, ajax, datatables

I'm getting this warning working with Datatables with server side processing, "DataTables warning: table id=kt_datatable - Requested unknown parameter 'ID' for row 0, column 0.", the database name is "Facturas" and has the columns:" id,tipo,cif_nif,numero_factura,fecha_desde,fecha_hasta,importe_desde,importe_hasta"

this is the html part:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-checkable" id="kt_datatable">
                            <thead>
                          <tr>
                                          <th>ID</th>
                                          <th>Tipo</th>
                                          <th>CIF / NIF</th>
                                          <th>N Factura</th>
                                          <th>Cliente</th>
                                          <th>Fecha desde</th>
                                          <th>Fecha hasta</th>
                                          <th>Importe Desde</th>
                                          <th>Importe Hasta</th>
                                          
                                          <th>Actions</th>
                              </tr>
                </thead>


                    <tfoot>
            <tr>
                                  <th>ID</th>
                                  <th>Tipo</th>
                                  <th>CIF / NIF</th>
                                  <th>N Factura</th>
                                  <th>Cliente</th>
                                  <th>Fecha desde</th>
                                  <th>Fecha hasta</th>
                                  <th>Importe Desde</th>
                                  <th>Importe Hasta</th>
                                  <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
            </tfoot>
            </table>
```

and this is the javascript part:

```
$.fn.dataTable.Api.register('column().title()', function() {
    return $(this.header()).text().trim();
});

var initTable1 = function() {
    // begin first table
    var table = $('#kt_datatable').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        // Pagination settings
        dom: `<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>
        <'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-7 dataTables_pager'lp>>`,
        // read more: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html

        lengthMenu: [5, 10, 25, 50],

        pageLength: 10,

        language: {
            'lengthMenu': 'Display _MENU_',
        },

        searchDelay: 500,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url: 'server-side.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                // parameters for custom backend script demo
                columnsDef: [
                    'ID','tipo', 'cif_nif', 'numero_factura', 'cliente', 'fecha_desde',
                    'fecha_hasta', 'importe_desde', 'importe_hasta', 'Actions',],
            }, 
        },
        columns: [
            {data: 'ID'},
            {data: 'tipo'},
            {data: 'cif_nif'},
            {data: 'numero_factura'},
            {data: 'cliente'},
            {data: 'fecha_desde'},
            {data: 'fecha_hasta'},
            {data: 'importe_desde'},
            {data: 'importe_hasta'},
            {data: 'Actions', responsivePriority: -1},
        ],
        columnDefs: [
            {
                targets: -1,
                title: 'Actions',
                orderable: false,
                render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
                    return '\
                        <div class="dropdown dropdown-inline">\
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon" data-toggle="dropdown">\
                                <i class="la la-cog"></i>\
                            </a>\
                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-sm dropdown-menu-right">\
                                <ul class="nav nav-hoverable flex-column">\
                                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="nav-icon la la-edit"></i><span class="nav-text">Edit Details</span></a></li>\
                                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="nav-icon la la-leaf"></i><span class="nav-text">Update Status</span></a></li>\
                                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="nav-icon la la-print"></i><span class="nav-text">Print</span></a></li>\
                                </ul>\
                            </div>\
                        </div>\
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon" title="Edit details">\
                            <i class="la la-edit"></i>\
                        </a>\
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon" title="Delete">\
                            <i class="la la-trash"></i>\
                        </a>\
                    ';
                },
            },
        
        ],
    });
```

and the server side php code is this (example was taken from datatables.net):

```
                   <?php

                   // DB table to use
                  $table = 'facturas';

                  // Table's primary key
                  $primaryKey = 'id';

                  // Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
                  // The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
                  // parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple
                  // indexes

                  $columns = array(
                    array( 'db' => 'id', 'dt' => 0 ),
                    array( 'db' => 'tipo', 'dt' => 1 ),
                    array( 'db' => 'cif_nif',  'dt' => 2 ),
                    array( 'db' => 'numero_factura',   'dt' => 3 ),
                    array( 'db' => 'cliente',     'dt' => 4 ),
array(
    'db'        => 'fecha_desde',
    'dt'        => 5,
    'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
        return date( 'jS M y', strtotime($d));
    }
),
array(
    'db'        => 'fecha_hasta',
    'dt'        => 6,
    'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
        return date( 'jS M y', strtotime($d));
    }
),
array(
    'db'        => 'importe_desde',
    'dt'        => 7,
    'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
        return date( 'jS M y', strtotime($d));
    }
),
array(
    'db'        => 'importe_hasta',
    'dt'        => 8,
    'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
        return date( 'jS M y', strtotime($d));
    }
)
);

               // SQL server connection information

           $sql_details = array(
                         'user' => 'root',
                         'pass' => '',
                         'db'   => 'nubelo',
                         'host' => 'localhost'
                            );


                      require( 'ssp.class.php' );

                  echo json_encode(
                             SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
                              );



              ?>
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to write "id" instead of "ID" ?